# what is the best way for learning graphics in c# with directx

Tags: c#

what is the best book for learning graphics in c# with directx

Comment: Way too vague. You need to add more detail.

Comment: I'm noticing a trend amongst a couple users tonight...

Comment: What kind of graphics? 2D or 3D? There's OpenGL, DirectX, GDI+, Cairo, etc.

Comment: @Jon: The trend is n00bishness, methinks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to be more specific as there are now a variety of ways to do graphics in C#. But, whichever technology you choose, you learn by doing. There are only so many API calls in any given graphics library. You become good by learning the ins and outs of each one and getting a good sense for how things fit into a 2d/3d space of your library. What's it take to draw a line? Animate motion? How do you layer things front to back? Keys to fast, efficient animation. etc.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.riemers.net/ (he also has a book), although I don't think its been updated for a while and may be getting a little out of date these days.